# why does -openWithCompletionHandler so slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a CoreData database that has 3 Entities:"Card", "Record", "Stat", Only "Card" has about 3000 objects in it and "Card" has no blob attribute (I know blob attribute may be slow), the other 2 Entities has no objects.

I debugged on my iPhone4, When it was opening the database, I found it quite slow,

here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"database start open...");
        [self.database openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"copy & open success: %d", success);
            callback(YES);
        }];
```

here is the logs:

```
2013-05-13 13:11:54.776 SuiShouBei[1670:707] database start open...
2013-05-13 13:11:54.943 SuiShouBei[1670:1b03] CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Applications/850D8AFD-BA6E-4E64-A150-507D5CD645FB/Documents/Default Database/StoreContent/persistentStore"
2013-05-13 13:11:54.950 SuiShouBei[1670:1b03] CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200
2013-05-13 13:11:54.956 SuiShouBei[1670:1b03] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
2013-05-13 13:11:57.941 SuiShouBei[1670:707] copy & open success: 1
```

From the CoreData log, it spent 3 seconds to **SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA**, and these fields and data are managed by CoreCode framework itself. And sometimes it even took longer(>10s).

**I really don't know why it took so long, and how to make it faster ?**

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean it is not slow in opening database but retrieving data from it?

Comment: Yes, actually it's slow in "this select", and only slow in "this select". Later on, Retrieving objects from "Card" is pretty fast(~0.1s)

Comment: maybe you need an index.

Comment: There is only one row in Z_METADATA table, and this table is belong to CoreData

Comment: Please show the code in openWithCompletionHandler. And show the code where you are performing the fetch.

Comment: openWithCompletionHandler is just a method of UIManagedDocument from the SDK. Isn't it the standard way of opening a database file ?

Comment: I edited the title to make it more pertinent.